# Possible to rejoin domain without domain admin right after wiping PC?

Tags: windows, windows-domain

I am doing some lab with virtual machine and brainstormed this problem.

If I have a PC joined domain, with full local administrator right, can I backup the "domain credentials" (I don't actually know where the credential stored, may be SID, registry, system file or somewhere else..) and restore it after reinstalled the Windows?

You can assume the client is Windows 7, 8 or Windows 10 and the server is Windows 2008, 2012, or 2016 if Windows version does matter.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what your question is, but it works as follows:

A computer and a domaincontroller build a relationship.

This relationship is stored on both the local pc and the server.

When a computer is reinstalled or otherwise not part of the domain anymore, the server does not recognize the pc.

In order for the pc to become part of the domain again, you have to specify on the PC that you want it to be part of the domain. A login screen will appear and you enter the administrator username and password of an account `on the domain controller` to change both the local pc and the active directory.

You do not need to backup anything for this, just know the password of the domain controller's administrative account. If you don't have this password, get help from someone who does. There's no other way to become a member of a domain.

Given that you cannot somehow backup this trust relationship, you cannot tranfer it either from one pc to another.

Comment: I guess you could backup this relationship by a making  full disk image and keeping the original off-line. That should work for at least a very short period (same as moving the HDD with the joined OS to a new PC). But than you get into problems when you want to use both at the same time.

Comment: The relationship is not just part of the software, but hardware as well. If the mac address changes, the relationship will break.

Comment: Yes, I know this answer is the normal procedure, but I would like to know if I could backup the relationship if I have full local admin right, so I don't have to follow this normal procedure to use doamin admin right account to rejoin the domain. Besides, I think the mac address should remain unchanged as this is the same PC

Comment: @Bilo he has answered your question. The answer is "no".

Comment: @Burgi Although it is no, I would like to know the behind scene reason of the "no"

Comment: The reason behind the scene is the fact that this relationship is located on both the server and the client, and unless you have an image of the entire OS, the server will not identify this as the same pc. Answering which exact registry keys and files you need to backup is outside of the scope of SuperUser.